# taskbar icons (example: eject USB icon beside the clock) has disappeared. How do I bring it back?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

as above. Also my search bar has disappeared at around the same time.

I have not updated my windows (I've changed the group policy so I have to manually download/install updates).

I've looked at various discussions on the net but none is working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely in Tablet Mode. You can [toggle Tablet Mode in the Action Center](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-tablet-mode-on-or-off-add3fbce-5cb5-bf76-0f9c-8d7b30041f30).

A list of the things you have looked into and tried as well as a screenshot would be really helpful for giving a better answer.